# How I can make my if conditions work in cypress?

Tags: if-statement, cypress

I want to check an element's visibility. In this code, cypress tries to find `cy.get('[data-cy="repetitions-count-box"]')` and fails if it not exist. It should go in else part, but doesn't.
Any suggestions?  [cypress fail message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgUiZ.png)

```
cy.get('[data-cy="repetitions-count-box"]').then(($rptBox) =>{
                if($rptBox.is(':visible')){
                        const repeat = $rptBox.text()
                        Cypress.env('repeatNumber', repeat)
                        cy.log(repeat)
                   
                }else{
                    cy.log('There is no repetition.')
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you locate that "dynamic" selector, `repetitions-count-box` outside the conditions. You have to find it in a static parent element which will always be rendered, e.g. `.app`:

```
    cy.get('.app').then($app => {
        if ($app.find('[data-cy="repetitions-count-box"]').is(':visible')) {

        // ...

        } else {

       // ...
        
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery length to check the presence of the element in the dom and apply the if-else condition. If length is greater than 0 that means the element exists in the DOM.

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  if ($body.find('[data-cy="repetitions-count-box"]').length > 0) {
    //Element exists
    const repeat = $rptBox.text()
    Cypress.env('repeatNumber', repeat)
    cy.log(repeat)
  } else {
    //Element doesn't exist
    cy.log('There is no repetition.')
  }
})
```